# border raduis not applying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a round image in next.js + tailwind CSS, Like a fully rounded image same as the profile Image. But when I use rounded-full class in my Image component by next.js its not fully rounded like the profile image how can i fix that with my code?

also this issue only comes with next/image not HTML img tag

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/wolf-dog-breeds-siberian-husky-1570411330.jpg?crop=1xw:0.84375xh;center,top"
        width={48}
        height={48}
        objectFit="cover"
        className="rounded-full"
        alt={"Image"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** To produce a circle with `rounded-full` (`border-radius: 9999px`), you'd need to ensure the image is square.

[Check this GitHub Discussion on Tailwind CSS](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/12313#discussioncomment-7411720)

---

The `rounded-full` class somehow didn't work for me either..

Try using a `style` like `clipPath: 'circle()'`. That worked out for me.

Check this out:

```
<Image
        src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/wolf-dog-breeds-siberian-husky-1570411330.jpg"
        width={48}
        height={48}
        objectFit="cover"
        style={{clipPath: 'circle()'}}
        alt={"Image"}
      />
```

Comment: Hey I also checked it out on GitHub, they said that `border-radius` needs an image to be a square if your want to make it rounded.
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/12313#discussioncomment-7411720